# generate Doc for android app in eclipse

Tags: android, javadoc, doc

hi i m trying to create java doc of my app, i done all comment in java file but when i generate a doc from eclipse(select project->Project->Generate JavaDoc..)  the Doc is generate properly but some method(Override) like (onCreate)

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
```

so now i try with doxygen it display all methods of class but no variables are displayed
can any one help me in this i don't no what is wrong, or i miss any option in doxygenfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your application variables are declare with **modifier(like public, private, ..)**? 
I think after declare with modifier, it displays in document.